# Automatically activating conda environments in fish

Tags: conda, fish

Is this possible? With virtualenv I used to use virtualfish, but there doesn't seem to be a conda equivalent. For bash I've found https://github.com/chdoig/conda-auto-env which also references https://github.com/sotte/conda_auto_activate.

Alternatively, a fish plugin which automatically runs when in a particular directory would work just about as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible.  Inspired by this line in the fish documentation (emphasis mine):

**Autoloading Functions**

When fish encounters a command, it attempts to autoload a function for that command, by looking for **a file with the name of that command** in ~/.config/fish/functions/.

---

So we can have a function that checks the folder on every 'cd' command and run the script to activate where appropriate. Easier to do it if you have only one VE.

May be the solution is to check for a certain script file that switches the VE in the new directory and execute it if it exists.  (That has to take care of how to handle the case where you switch directly to a subdirectory.)

---

**Updated after a counter question from the OP:**
Here is what I had in mind.  Say we copy this function to a file called ~/.config/fish/functions/cd.fish:

```
# search for a myInit.fish file UP THE DIRECTORY TREE, starting from the current folder.
# if found, execute it.
# Intended for automatically switching to the python  virtual environment on entering the
# directories.  Can put in other initialization stuff.

function cd --description 'change directory - fish overload'

    builtin cd $param $argv

    set -l check_dir (pwd)
    # if myInit.fish is found in the home directory:
    if test -f "$check_dir/myInit.fish"
        source $check_dir/myInit.fish
        echo "executed: source $check_dir/myInit.fish"
        return
    end

    # Look up the directory tree for myInit.fish:
    set check_dir (string split -r -m 1 / $check_dir)[1]

    while test $check_dir
        if test -f "$check_dir/myInit.fish"
            source $check_dir/myInit.fish
            echo "executed: source $check_dir/myInit.fish"
            break;
        else
            set check_dir (string split -r -m 1 / $check_dir)[1]
        end  # if ... else ...
    end  # while 
end  # function
```

---

Say you wanted to switch to a VE named "VEOpenCV" when you switch to either OpenCV directory or one of its subdirectories.  For that, create a file in the OpenCV directory and call it myInit.fish and put the following line in there:

```
activate VEOpenCV
```

To deactivate the VE when you switch to the home directory, create another myInit.fish file in the home directory and put in the 'deactivate' command in there. If not, just create an empty myInit.fish file in the home directory to terminate the directory traversal.

If you prefer not to overload the 'builtin cd', change the name of the function above to 'myCd' or whatever and rename the file to match that.  Then call

```
%> myCd OpenCV
```

instead of

```
%> cd OpenCV
```

I did **not** test it extensively; but the limited testing succeeded.  If it does not work, post a note here.

And, don't forget to post debugs/improvements/bugs and other relevant information - or a better solution you may find, here!

Comment: Thanks, but this is to autoload functions, which I believe (based on my limited understanding) to just mean it will define the function so that it can be called from the shell, rather than running the function itself. This is based on the text from the docs which says "An autoloaded function becomes available automatically to all running shells."

Comment: I posted an update to my original posting: what better way to spend my Friday evening than write some shell script :-).  Check it out.

Comment: Thanks much! Obvious issue is infinite looping when cd-ing to a path not under your home folder, also I think your while loop should be using check_dir rather than cur_dir. Also the line in myInit.fish should be `conda activate VEOpenCV`. Otherwise this works though!

Comment: The program **should** terminate under all conditions.  There is no cur_dir in the current version - you probably copied it while i was still editing.